# QGIS Field Calculator Update Existing Field

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 2.18 and am trying to replace the values in an existing column. The errors I get are that Replace doesn't have the right number of arguments and the no root node error.

This is likely a python thing and I'm not that experienced in python. The example indicates three parts: input string, replace string, the output string.  I want to replace the whole thing.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The double quotes aren't needed. Instead, you need to use this syntax:

```
replace('Buildings 3-5', 'Buildings 3-5', 'Tourism')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using double quotes in front on the argument that were unnecessary.